# netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib libdnshostprio.so

Tags: android, api

I know there are already similar questions, but I have a different problem. The problems related to this error are already discussed; they contain webview or webdialog, but in my code, there is no webview or webdialog at all. Still, as I hit any API, I get this error!! Please help.

Ask me for any code if required.

I got these lines of errors in my logcat:

```
netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib libdnshostprio.so
netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: libdnshostprio.so
netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: spl_proc_plugin.so
netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib pp_proc_plugin.so
netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: pp_proc_plugin.so
netstack:  STAT_HUB - App *MY APP PACKAGE* isn't supported
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add the internet premission in the manifest file

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```